# Custom deserialize from json object string

Tags: c#, json, serialization, javascriptserializer

I'm trying to deserialize this JSON into an object but I can't reach the solution.

Json format:

```
{"option1":
  {"field1":"true","field2":"false"},
 "option2":
  {"field1":"true","field2":"false"}}
```

I Have the following object:

```
[Serializable]
public class genericFieldOptions
{
    public string option { get; set; }
    public string field { get; set; }
    public bool value{ get; set; }
}
```

And then the "deserializer":

```
public class genericFieldsConverter : JavaScriptConverter
{
    public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
    {
        get
        {
            return new[] { typeof(genericFieldOptions) };
        }
    }

    public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        List<genericFieldOptions> p = new List<genericFieldOptions>();

        foreach (var entry in dictionary.Keys)
        {             
            try
            {
                Dictionary<string, Boolean> test = (Dictionary<string, Boolean>)dictionary[entry];//error
                p.Add(new genericFieldOptions { key = entry,   field1=test["field1"],field2=test["field2"]  });
            }
            catch { }
        }
        return p;
    }
```

The call:

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
serializer.RegisterConverters(new JavaScriptConverter[] { new genericFieldsConverter() });
var example= serializer.Deserialize<List<genericFieldOptions>>(json);
```

How can I access the `IDictionary<string, object>` as `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,boolean>>` ? Or is it just impossible?

What am I doing wrong? Is there another easy way to do this?

Comment: Indeed there is another easy way - use [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) :-)

Comment: You can copy the JSON String from your question and put the cursor in your namespace where your model needs to be created. Goto -- Edit-PasteSpecial->As JSON CLASS...... and then add a package using NewtonSoft.Json; at the top and assign header to each property of model/class as [JsonProperty("option1 OR option2")]..... Hint

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to correctly make objects that represent the serialized values.  So for:

```
{"option1":
  {"field1":"true","field2":"false"},
 "option2":
  {"field1":"true","field2":"false"}}
```

I would make:

```
public class Options
{
  public Option Option1 { get; set; }
  public Option Option2 { get; set; }
}

public class Option
{
  public bool Field1 { get; set; }
  public bool Field2 { get; set; }
}
```

For beginners, one of the easier ways is to use http://json2csharp.com/.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that's why I'm trying to do it generic, I don't want to do declare all time new options. There is another way?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you can use [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json). If you don't want to create classes to deserialise to, you can use dictionaries as you have tried, or you could use a `dynamic`.

```
const string json = "{\"option1\":{\"field1\":true,\"field2\":false}," +
                    "\"option2\":{\"field1\":true,\"field2\":false}}";

var result1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, bool>>>(json);
Console.WriteLine(result1["option2"]["field1"]);

dynamic result2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
Console.WriteLine(result2.option2.field1);
```

Comment: For the one seeking the answer, since you mentioned not wanting to create a model everytime, consider using dynamic. As stated above. But take note dynamic resolves things at runtime. If your code doesn't match the value on runtime then it will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have chosen to use [javascriptserializer](/questions/tagged/javascriptserializer), firstly you need to do your conversion at the level of the `List<genericFieldOptions>` not the `genericFieldOptions`, because the serializer cannot convert a JSON object to a `List<T>` automatically.

Secondly, rather than casting the nested dictionaries to `Dictionary<string, Boolean>`, you need to cast to `IDictionary<string, object>` and then *deserialize* each value to a `bool` using [`JavaScriptSerializer.ConvertToType<bool>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356489%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Thus:

```
public class genericFieldsListConverter : JavaScriptConverter
{
    public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
    {
        get
        {
            return new[] { typeof(List<genericFieldOptions>) };
        }
    }

    public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        var query = from entry in dictionary
                   let subDictionary = entry.Value.AsJsonObject()
                   where subDictionary != null
                   from subEntry in subDictionary
                   select new genericFieldOptions { option = entry.Key, field = subEntry.Key, value = serializer.ConvertToType<bool>(subEntry.Value) };
        return query.ToList();
    }

    public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        var list = (IList<genericFieldOptions>)obj;
        if (list == null)
            return null;
        return list
            .GroupBy(o => o.option)
            .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => (object)g.ToDictionary(o => o.field, o => serializer.Serialize(o.value)));
    }
}

public static class JavaScriptSerializerObjectExtensions
{
    public static bool IsJsonObject(this object obj)
    {
        return obj is IDictionary<string, object>;
    }

    public static IDictionary<string, object> AsJsonObject(this object obj)
    {
        return obj as IDictionary<string, object>;
    }
}
```